# Different this binding in JS

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have this object:

```js
    var a = {
      b: 42,
      c: function() {
          return this;
         }
    }
    
    console.log((a.c)());
    console.log((a.c || [])());
```

Why is the return value (object bound to `this`) of `(a.c)()` different from `(a.c || [])()`?

Comment: I’ve read somewhere that expressions such as `(a.c || [])` generally don’t retain the `this` context, but `(a.c)` is kind of an exception, where it doesn’t matter how many parentheses you put around it. Even `((((a)).c))` will work. It’s in the spec somewhere.

Comment: I think [this explanation from MSN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_value_of_this_within_the_handler) also covers the above example as a reason as to why. Essentially `this` refers to the `this` scope of it's parent (global/window if not anchored to another function/object)